# I want to create dynamic pagination thats the function which is selecting from the database

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

*Variable *not defined but its defined in the getAllproducts not sure why its saying that when its declared

```
    public function getAllProducts(){
      $limit = 12;
      $page = isset($_GET['page'])  ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
      $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        $this->db->query("SELECT tbl_products. * ,  tbl_users.username, tbl_users.avatar, categories.name FROM tbl_products
                                            INNER JOIN tbl_users
                                            ON tbl_products.users_id = tbl_users.user_id
                                            INNER JOIN categories
                                            ON tbl_products.categories_id = categories.cat_id
                                            ORDER BY created_date DESC
                                            limit $start,$limit");
        $results = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $results;

        $this->db->query('SELECT count(pro_id)  AS pro_id  FROM tbl_products');
        $row = $this->db->resultSet();
        $total = $row[0]['pro_id'];
        $pages = ceil($total / $limit);
        
        return $this->db->rowCount();
    }
```

There other code is here

```
   <?php if($products) : ?>
 <div class="container">

   <?php foreach( $products as $product ) : ?>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="img/products/<?php echo $product->image; ?>" alt="">
        <div class="title"><a  href="product.php?pro_id=<?php echo  $product->pro_id; ?>"><?php echo $product->title; ?></a></div>
        <div class="desc"><?php echo trimtext($product->descs ,0,85); ?></div>
    </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php for ($i=1; $i < $pages; $i++) : ?>
      <a  href="products.php?pages=<?php $i; ?>"><?php $i; ?> </a>
      <?php  endfor ; ?>
 </div>
<?php else : ?>
   <div class="error"><p>No Products Posted Yet</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I really appreciate your help in advance

i Searched on google i couldn't find the desired result
i tried passing the data in the function nothing not sure why am new

i want the pages to be generated dynamically from the database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcqND.png)